# Bold and italic label of axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, axis

How to write this x in xlabel bold and italic?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties    

plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{lmodern}"]
params = {'text.usetex' : True,
          'font.size' : 14,
          'font.family' : 'lmodern',
          'text.latex.unicode': True,
          }
plt.rcParams.update(params)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.annotate('x', xy=(0.93, -0.01), ha='left', va='top', xycoords='axes fraction', weight='bold', style='italic')

plt.show()
```

Adding of `from matplotlib import rc` does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using normal text

Use `weight` and `style` arguments:

```
ax.annotate("x", ..., weight='bold', style='italic')
```

#### Using Latex

i.e. when `rcParams["usetex"] = True`,

```
ax.annotate(r'\textbf{\textit{x}}', ...)
```

as seen e.g. in [correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text)

Comment: I wrote 
`ax.annotate('x', xy=(0.93, -0.01), ha='left', va='top', xycoords='axes fraction', weight='bold', style='italic')` and x is not bold and italic. Can be the problem in setting `plt.rcParams`?

Comment: The problem *may* be that you use a font which does not have a bold italic character set.

Comment: I use lmodern as a font. In LaTeX it has italic and bold

Comment: Are you using latex here?

Comment: How to use it please? Should I import latex? That might be the mistake.

Comment: No, that was a question. If you're not using latex, it is irrelevant if a latex font has italic and bold characters, because you're not using it anyways. So `lmodern` is a ttf font?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201128/discussion-between-archie-and-importanceofbeingernest).

Comment: So in the question there is no indication for latex being in use. Please read and understand [mcve].

Comment: How to write this? `plt.text(42, 52.3, r'\textbf{\textit{$q^t(q)$}}')`. It is not bold

Comment: Bold italic math mode is hard. I'd start [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14395/bold-italic-vectors).

Comment: I don't know how to import packages. I tried `from latex import bm` but this led to an error

Comment: You already do import a latex package in your code, namely `lmodern`. So it's just the same for any other package.